# Aurora MySQL - How Much IOPS Am I Using?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I am testing Aurora MySQL as a possible replacement to Aurora Postgres. When bulk loading data into Aurora Postgres, it's very easy to see how mush Postgres is going to cost just by looking at the IOPS on a bulk load.

[image: 40k]

But MySQL does not have a similar metric (Write IOPS). The only metric that looks comparable is Write Throughput. But after looking 800k rows into my MySQL DB I get nothing:

[image: flatline]

It's not possible here that i've had an average of 0.5 inserts/s, because I just loaded it with 800k rows.

My method for loading MySQL is a `LOAD DATA FROM S3 FILE` statement if it makes a difference.

How can I see my consumed Aurora I/O?

How can I know how much this is going to cost if I go ahead and load another 300mm rows into this table?

Is Insert Throughput and Select Throughput equivalent to IOPS?